# MediaWiki: How do I use an AJAX POST in JS to send data to a custom API extension (PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mediawiki-extensions

I've been stumped on this for a while. I've successfully created a MediaWiki API extension from which I'm able to extract data using an API url, but now I want to go the other way. I want to use JS to send a simple bit of data to the server for storage in a session variable (in PHP). I've experimented with something like the following:

```
        $.ajax({
            // start POST request
            type: "POST",
            // url to which the request is sent
            url: "/",
            // data to the server
            data: { myvariable: 0 },
            // Type of data
            dataType: 'json',
            // Funciton to be called if the request succeeds
            success: function( data ){
                console.log("POST successful with " + data);
            }

        })
```

What I don't fundamentally get is how to "pick up" the POSTed data in PHP. In my research, I came upon something saying I should look for $_POST['myvariable'] in PHP. Yet I'm not sure how or where I'd create something that would listen for such a POST from JS. It seems to me the easiest solution to this would be if I could write a method onto my API extension that simply assigns the value of the myvariable that's POSTed to the session variable whenever that thing is POSTed. I've written this method already, in fact, but it's unclear to me how I'd instruct AJAX to invoke it in PHP. I've also read that this type of thing may not be advisable for security reasons.

I've seen advice elsewhere suggesting I should do something in JS like:

```
var api = new mw.Api();
```

...and then use the Api object's methods to execute Ajax GET and POST requests. Well, I tried creating an instance of this object, and it throws errors on the console that say it's not a recognized function or something of that nature.

I'm rather new at all this, but I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out something that in theory ought to be very simple. Any suggestions?

Comment: The "mediawiki" module may be undefined indeed, have you tried looking for the ResourceLoader docs on how to load it?

Comment: ...that is, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceModules